# The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, endpoint

I need to call a web-service, that is built using axis2. When I try to call this service, it throw an exception.
This exception is: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference.
In the wsdl file I set the location property to: http://localhost:8080/SMSWebServer/services/SMSWS.

In the client I use that endpoint to call the web-service.

Someone can tell me why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: While I consume services in heterogenous environs, and deal with mixed architectures, I do not have the depth on Java to point you to a "A will fix your problem" answer. Having said that ...

I would start here:
http://www.keith-chapman.org/2009/02/axis2-endpoint-reference-epr-for.html

There is a link to an article that explains more detail to solving the problem. The simple answer is there is something wrong with the mapping to the endpoint you are trying to hit. Once you cure that problem, you will be running again.

Comment: dead link please review the answer